# Redirect to Bootstrap modal instead of error404, Django request.user

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with an request.user statement in Django. 
Through those all hours what I wanted to achieve is:

- Only the "user" (author) of the ShiftReport (simply a post) should be able to edit the ShiftReport.

So far I have managed to do that, and when I am logged in as another user I receive an error 404, whereas logged in as a post creator I am able to edit the post - Great!.

However, instead of that 404 Error I would just like to throw a Bootstrap modal saying access denied.

My 'views.py':

```
def update(request, shiftreport_id=None):
title = 'Edit Shift Report by'
instance = get_object_or_404(ShiftReport, pk=shiftreport_id, user=request.user)
form = shiftreportForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
confirm_message = None

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()

    title = "Thanks"
    confirm_message = "Shift Report has been updated!"
    form = None

context = {
    "title": title,
    "instance": instance,
    "form": form,
    "confirm_message": confirm_message,
}
return render(request, 'shift/edit.html', context)
```

My 'detail.html':

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="{% url 'new' %}">New Shift Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'all' %}">All Shift Reports</a></li>
        {% if not request.user %}
```

> with above statement I can edit my own post and I get Error404 when I
>   want to edit a post from another user.
>   When I change it to {% if request.user %}, my modal works but then I cannot edit any of the posts, neither mine neither from another user.

```
        <li><a href="#restrictedit" data-toggle="modal">Edit Shift Report Nr.{{ shiftreport.id }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#restrictdelete" data-toggle="modal">Delete Shift Report</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'detail' shiftreport.id %}edit/">Edit Shift Report Nr.{{ shiftreport.id }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#confirm" data-toggle="modal">Delete Shift Report</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="GET" action="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search..." value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Hope construction of my question make sense a little, the issue on the other hand doesn't make any sense to me... would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try not to use get_object_or_404 instead use objects.get and handle the response manually when it retuns 0.

Comment: please update `instance = get_object_or_404(ShiftReport, pk=shiftreport_id, user=request.user)` to `instance = get_object_or_404(ShiftReport, pk=shiftreport_id)` it will work.

Comment: Hi Jingo, I have tried that, believe me and I have searched a lot on both matters. If I do ShiftReport.objects.get(pk=shiftreport_id, user=request.user) I ran off course into an "ShiftReport matching query does not exis" as it doesn't recognise the user ID. It doesn't remain on my template and run the modal as I would like it to. If I remove user=request.user from the arguments my if statement in the template doesn't work anymore and I can edit all the posts.. I am wrapping my head around it already few hours and most likely it's something small that I can't see and it's causing a me aheadache

Comment: @vinaykumar - if I do that, I can edit all the posts, that's not what I want. please see above reply.

Comment: @user3360412 you can compare `instance.user==request.user`. and put you login based on it.

Comment: @vinaykumar you mean in template or in views? I tried both ways and I either get my desired modal pop up, or I can edit all the posts. It's one way or another, I cannot combine those two actions to get a modal and a blockage to edit the posts not created by my user.

Comment: @user3360412 why are you putting condition in modal template? you can use ajax call to fetch template, base on you condition.

Comment: @vinaykumar most likely due to my monthly experience ;) Anyways, I am now researching your advise. Hope I can get somewhere from there but it will probably take me a lot of time, I was counting for a quick fix from this community to a problem that for sure was already solved. Thanks for your input.